# How to see plist variables result from Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an info.plist file with variables inside, such as ${PRODUCT_NAME} or ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.

Where does there variables reference to?

And how do I know these variables will be converted into what string by Xcode?

Comment: this variables comes from build settings. 'Product Bundle Identifier', 'Product Name'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer,

$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) and $(PRODUCT_NAME) comes from,

[image]

And ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} is concatenation of:

$EXECUTABLE_PREFIX, $PRODUCT_NAME and $EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.

All are in Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know how to read the variable's result by Xcode?