# How to read environment variables in info.plist?

Tags: ios, plist

I am setting a variable in the terminal

```
export VAR=1.0.0
```

And I have to read it from ~/.bash_profile into the info.plist like for example:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>VAR</string>
```

So like this I can do automated builds. Is there a way how to read the variables?

Comment: Maybe will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code

Comment: Right now I am trying to read a ~/.bash_profile variable and add it into info.plists. Not sure with the abouve example will work but ill try more ways. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 5):

In the `info.plist` you reference the variable:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(VAR)</string>
```

Then when you build the project from the terminal you inject the value for the VAR:

```
xcodebuild build VAR=123 -project myProject.xcodeproj -target myTarget -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Or if the variable in set in the environment:

```
xcodebuild build VAR=${VAR} -project myProject.xcodeproj -target myTarget -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this link on SO,

[PLIST Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40041309/6742121)

$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) and $(PRODUCT_NAME) comes from Build Settings.

And ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} is concatenation of:

$EXECUTABLE_PREFIX, $PRODUCT_NAME and $EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I realised that I have not specified everything in my question so I have edited a bit. Maybe you know a way around.

Comment: The question was about environment variables in the build environment and not about referring to other variables or values inside the `info.plist`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `bundle` to access the `Info.plist`.

```
 let v = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
```

Comment: Accessing the `info.plist` is not related to the question.